# How to mock struct methods in Golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I'm reading this page (I'm not using Amazon, just reading for golang education)

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/mocking-out-then-aws-sdk-for-go-for-unit-testing/

When I try it for myself, I get type errors.

```
type Queue struct {
    Client ThirdPartyStruct
    URL    string
}

type mockedReceiveMsgs struct {
    ThirdPartyStruct
    Resp ValueIWantToMock
}

q := Queue{Client: mockedReceiveMsgs{}}
```

When I try to do the exact same thing, I get

```
cannot use mocked literal (type mockedReceiveMsgs) as type ThirdPartyStruct in field value
```

I feel like I'm copying the Amazon tutorial exactly. How come in there code, mockedReceiveMsgs can be used in place of ThirdPartyStruct?

Comment: You're using a struct, aws is using an interface.

Comment: Follow-up: How can I mock ThirdPartyStruct's methods? Assume I'm only allowed to touch the tests so I can't replace the current code by wrapping it inside of RealThirdPartyStruct.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with mocking but with the fact that Queue structure includes ThirdPartyStruct by value (as a substructure), not as a pointer. And so does mockedReceiveMsgs. It just so happened that in Queue structure this substructure can be accessed by Client name and in mockedReceiveMsgs it is supposedly "anonymous" (but actually can be referred by ThirdPartyStruct name if required).

So, `q := Queue{Client: mockedReceiveMsgs{}}` actually tries to copy over mockedReceiveMsgs into Client and it obviously fails as it has extra bits, which don't fit into ThirdPartyStruct. You can make it compile by changing it to `q := Queue{Client: mockedReceiveMsgs{}.ThirdPartyStruct}` though I doubt this is what you want.

Note, that if you change `Client ThirdPartyStruct` to `Client interface{}` (in your original example) then it will compile as well. And this is most likely what you want. And it will also work with any interface type. Which is what @tkausl most likely was pointing out. The only tricky bit is pointer semantics vs value semantics when you're implementing your interface. It does back fire sometimes. See a quick example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ABaH95gbnOA)

Answer (score 0):

If `ThirdPartyStruct` is, as it's name implies, a `struct` type as opposed to an `interface` type, then you cannot mock it, it is just not possible in Go. If you read your example article carefully and follow the [link that shows the definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/sqs/sqsiface/#SQSAPI) of `SQSAPI` you'll see that it is an `interface` type.

`type SQSAPI`**`interface`**`{`

To make your code "mockable" you need to use an interface type for the `Client` field. Here's an example that is more true to the aws one: https://play.golang.org/p/puhhgmFCUC4